# Alarm when battery get full charged

Tags: java, android

Hello I am trying to get status of battery of the device programmatically. So I am looking to get battery status that give idea whether  it is fully charged or not. Any idea to achieve this ?

Comment: Let me google it for you: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: @Earl If you want stackoverflow users to Google something before they post questions, how do you think this community was built? I have seen more straightforward questions than this on SO.

Comment: @bot Yes, you're right :) I might have answered that question and gained some additional reputation, but I grumbled and missed the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're programming for Android devices:

You should create a `BroadcastReceiver` for the battery status. It's described as a tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

I assume you already know how to program the Android via its API. If not, you have some things to learn first: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html